# Best Practice for Load Balancing Strategy in 3 Tier Architecture

Tags: architecture, system, load-balancing, 3-tier, infrastructure

Before going into questions, please let me clarify my terminology.

**3 Tier Architecture** - Not normal client, logic and data access layer that is talked about in Web Application. It is more referring to infrastructure (or system) level. 3 Tiers consists of Web, Application and Database Tier.

**Web Tier** - Consists of Web servers that does proxy job. E.g. IIS Rewrite

**Application Tier** - Consists of Application servers that have actual source code of application. E.g. ASP.NET Application

**Database Tier** - Consists of Database servers that stores data. E.g. MS SQL Server.

I have two overall architecture as you can see below.
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKVx0.jpg)

And what would be the better practice between figure 1 and figure 2(or maybe pros and cons). I am considering in aspects of High Availability (HA), Maintainability, Complexity, Separation of Concern, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That additional layer of load balancing will be fairly expensive if you need to support session state.   If your application is truly stateless it won't make a big difference.

My question would be,  why not combine your application and proxy tiers to the same hardware,  and have 4 nodes in your redundancy pool instead of two.   That would increase your actual redundancy,  plus eliminate a network hop. Your attack surface is already reduced by your hardware load balancer,.

Comment: The one of main reason for having two layers, web and app is due to security. Using reverse proxy in web layer, the client would not know where are resources originated from. That is reason for having multiple layering.

Comment: Are you using software that is fundamentally more secure in your reverse proxy layer?  Are you planning on not blindly proxying, but somehow constraining the url paths to somehow increase your security?  I've seen people do this before without fully understanding their HTTP stack, and why a reverse proxy only gives better security if you are using something that is somehow more hardened than their application layer.

Comment: Of course there must be security take in placed for application. However I think security in web application is not only making application secure. This is because application is running on top of OS and communicated through network. And that is reason why there is separate reverse proxy server for more security.

Comment: And also reverse proxy is not only about filtering HTTP request. That is yes for role of proxy server. But the word 'reverse' adding extra functionality of hiding original source of request. For more detail, you can refer to this link, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse